# The existence of complete Riemannian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complete-spaces

If $M$ is a differential manifold, can we necessarily find a complete Riemannian metric on $M$? (I know we can find a Riemannian metric without completeness assumption.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is yes, altought the construction is not simple. Given any metric on a differential manifold, it can be shown that it is conformally equivalent to a complete riemannian manifold.

Reference: Nomizu, Katsumi, and Hideki Ozeki. "The existence of complete Riemannian metrics." Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 12.6 (1961): 889-891.

http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2034383?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21105114015163is

Comment: Is there an easier proof if I don't care about staying in the same conformal class?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Not that I am aware of.

Comment: If you don't care about the conformal relation, there are two proofs given in "The Cauchy Problem in General Relativity" by Hans Ringstrom.  In my version, it's Lemma 11.1.  One is a partition of unity argument, the other uses Whitney's Embedding Theorem.  I don't know if you'd consider them easier, but it might be worth checking out.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Just in case this is still of interest, in the 2nd ed. of Lee's smooth manifolds book there are proofs outlined in exercises 13-17 (same conformal class), 13-18 (not same conformal class) on page 346.

Comment: @Matthew:  Actually, after reading the proof Jonas linked, the fact that it's in the same conformal class is a simple corollary to the proof.  Based on other "same conformal class" type results, I was anticipating analysis of PDEs (which I am not comfortable with).  But thank you for the reference - this gives me another reason why I should buy a new edition of the book!

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I haven't read the 1st edition, but I really like the 2nd edition! I just wrote a solution to Lee's 13-17 at the link below (hopefully it's correct :) ). I haven't yet looked at the paper linked by Jonas, so that proof might be the same as mine. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904941/every-riemannian-metric-is-conformally-related-to-a-complete-metric/2357883#2357883

Answer (score 2):

For a proof of Problem 13-17 [p.346] in Lee's Intro. to Smooth Manifolds (2nd ed.), see https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0133785-8/S0002-9939-1961-0133785-8.pdf. The following remarks may help readers read the above paper.

Remark 1. For the information about conformal metrics, read [On conformal metrics notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677824/on-conformal-metrics-notation). Conformal metrics $d,d'$ generate the same topology.

Remark 2. For all $x,y\in M$, if $S(x,r(x))\cap S(y,r(y))\neq\varnothing$, then $|r(x)-r(y)|=d(x,y)$; otherwise, $|r(x)-r(y)|<d(x,y)$.

Remark 3. $\omega (x)$ can be constructed by using partitions of unity. That is,  $\omega (x)$ is constructed by the formula given in p.46, l.$-$10, Lee's Intro. to Smooth Manifolds (2nd ed.) except that $j$ [the coefficient of $\psi_j$] should be replaced with the maximum of $r^{-1}$ on an appropriate compact set.

Remark 4. $(M,d')$ is complete.

Proof.
Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in  $(M,d')$.\
We may assume $\{x_n\}\subset S'(x_1,1/3)$. Since $S'(x_1,1/3)\subset S(x_1, r(x)/2)$ and the latter set is relatively compact in $(M,d)$, $\exists x\in \bar{S}(x_1, r(x)/2): x_n\to x$. Note that $x\in \bar{S}'(x_1,1/3)$.

This answer is taken from § 1.1, Remark 206 in my paper https://sites.google.com/view/lcwangpress/%E9%A6%96%E9%A0%81/papers/quantum-mechanics